# jQuery advanced selector

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Can I use comparison statements within a jQuery selector method?
eg.
I have a list of divs generated by php that all use the same CSS class but have value attributes of 1, 2, 3 etc. I also have a text input field with an id. This field can accept numbers only. I would like to select the div (from the long list) that has a value attribute that matches the value put into the text input box.
Can I write something like this:
$( '$(".someClass").val() == $("input#someId").val()' )

???

Comment: How can a DIV have a value attribute ?

Comment: any element can have any attribute. Though the HTML validation will not be positiv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.someClass').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('value') == $('input#someId').val() ;
 })
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the CSS3 selectors page: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/.

Recommended selector: E[foo="bar"], as in '.class[value="'+$('#inputId').val()+'"]'.

Note: not tested.

Answer (score 2):

it's just a standard jquery selector: [attributeEquals](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Just a test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#txtValue').change(function(){
            $('.selectMe').css('color', 'black');
            $('.selectMe[value= '+$(this).val()+']').css('color', 'red');
        });     
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtValue" value=""/>
    <div class="selectMe" value="1">one</div>
    <div class="selectMe" value="2">two</div>
    <div class="selectMe" value="3">three</div>
</body>
</html>
```